# where is catkin_make error log file location?

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After doing catkin_make, the output has an error but it is too long so I cannot see from the start. I would like to know where or how to I can find the error log file. I search everywhere but I cannot find the answer so I ask here. Sorry if this question is silly.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230286/where-is-catkin_make-error-log-file-location?/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make` doesn't output the build to a log file. It only prints it to the screen. You'll have to increase your console's scroll buffer so you can scroll back. Or you could pipe the output to a file with `catkin_make ... > path/to/file.log`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-03-28**:
Thanks William.